# How can I displayed images with different extension for my object detection web app from my sqlite database

Tags: javascript, python, html, sqlite, flask

I'm working on a flask object detection app, and to explain it briefly how I would like this to work: I store an uploaded image in my SQLite database, then click on a button named 'Show image' to display it. After this, I click on 'Detection', clicking on a button named 'Show annotated image' replace the original image by the annotated image. All the functions of the web app work except the display features.

Here the routes to display the images:

```python
@app.route('/display/<image_id>')
def displayImage(image_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('image_database.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT image_data FROM images WHERE id = ?', (image_id,))
    image_data = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    image_data_encoded = base64.b64encode(image_data)
    conn.close()
    return render_template('index.html', image_data=image_data_encoded)

@app.route('/display_detection/<image_id>')
def displayDetection(annotated_image_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('image_database.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT annotated_image_name FROM images WHERE id = ?', (annotated_image_id,))
    annotated_image_data = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    annotated_image_data_encoded = base64.b64encode(annotated_image_data)
    conn.close()
    return render_template('index.html', annotated_image_data=annotated_image_data_encoded)
```

In my html code I have a container for displaying images, but how can I use the same container for the two different sources ?

```html
        <div id="image-container" class="grid-item">
            <img id="displayed-image" src="{{ image_data }}" width="1000" height="640">
            <img id="displayed-annotated-image" src="{{ annotated_image_data }}" width="1000" height="640">
        </div>
```

I can't use something like that `src="data:image/jpg` because I want to display images with other format. and I don't know if I have to use javascript or php to resolve my problem as I have limited knowledge on those languages.

Thanks you in advance for your answers and advice.

Comment: When uploading, you can save the mime type associated with the image in another column of the database table. Then use these to correctly display the image according to type.

Comment: I tried with a wildcard ‘image/*’ to use all types of images but still have nothing.

Comment: As I mentioned, store the type in an additional database column. See [`FileStorage.mimetype`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.mimetype) or [`mimetypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#module-mimetypes), depending on how you store the image data.